# JS Text And Morse Code Converter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have run into a problem when running my JavaScript that turns regular text to Morse code.

When I attempt to run my function entering the text "I Love JS" nothing seems to happen.

Here's my code:

```
$("body").html('<textarea class="itext"></textarea><br/><text class="otext"></text><br/><button class="convert">Convert!!!</button>');

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var textandmorse = [
        {"letter":'A', 'morse':".-"},
        {"letter":'B', 'morse':"-..."},
        {"letter":'C', 'morse':"-.-."},
        {"letter":'D', 'morse':"-.."},
        {"letter":'E', 'morse':"."},
        {"letter":'F', 'morse':"..-."},
        {"letter":'G', 'morse':"--."},
        {"letter":'H', 'morse':"...."},
        {"letter":'I', 'morse':".."},
        {"letter":'J', 'morse':".---"},
        {"letter":'K', 'morse':"-.-"},
        {"letter":'L', 'morse':".-.."},
        {"letter":'M', 'morse':"--"},
        {"letter":'N', 'morse':"-."},
        {"letter":'O', 'morse':"---"},
        {"letter":'P', 'morse':".--."},
        {"letter":'Q', 'morse':"--.-"},
        {"letter":'R', 'morse':".-."},
        {"letter":'S', 'morse':"..."},
        {"letter":'T', 'morse':"-"},
        {"letter":'U', 'morse':"..-"},
        {"letter":'V', 'morse':"...-"},
        {"letter":'W', 'morse':".--"},
        {"letter":'X', 'morse':"-..-"},
        {"letter":'Y', 'morse':"-.--"},
        {"letter":'Z', 'morse':"--.."},
        {"letter":'1', 'morse':".----"},
        {"letter":'2', 'morse':"..---"},
        {"letter":'3', 'morse':"...--"},
        {"letter":'4', 'morse':"....-"},
        {"letter":'5', 'morse':"....."},
        {"letter":'6', 'morse':"-...."},
        {"letter":'7', 'morse':"--..."},
        {"letter":'8', 'morse':"---.."},
        {"letter":'9', 'morse':"----."},
        {"letter":'0', 'morse':"-----"},
        {"letter":'.', 'morse':".-.-.-"},
        {"letter":',', 'morse':"--..--"},
        {"letter":':', 'morse':"---..."},
        {"letter":'?', 'morse':"..--.."},
        {"letter":'\'', 'morse':".----."},
        {"letter":'-', 'morse':"-....-"},
        {"letter":'/', 'morse':"-..-."},
        {"letter":'(', 'morse':"-.--.-"},
        {"letter":')', 'morse':"-.--.-"},
        {"letter":'"', 'morse':".-..-."},
        {"letter":'@', 'morse':".--.-."},
        {"letter":'=', 'morse':"-...-"},
        {"letter":' ', 'morse':"/"}
        ];
        //var morse2text = [];
        //var text2morse = [];
        /*for (i = 0; i < textandmorse.length; i++) {
            console.log("letter"+textandmorse[i].letter+" morse"+textandmorse[i].morse);
        }*/

        // Replace Function
        String.prototype.replaceArray = function(find, replace) {
            var replaceString = this;
            var regex;
            for (var i = 0; i < find.length; i++) {
                regex = new RegExp(find[i], "g");
                replaceString = replaceString.replace(regex, replace[i]);
            }
            return replaceString;
        };

        // Declare IO Variable
        var itext = $(".itext");
        var otext = $(".otext");
        var brun = $(".convert");

        // Function Text And Morse
        function tam(from, metode, log, type) {
            for (i = 0; i < textandmorse.length; i++) {
                var letter = textandmorse[i].letter;
                var morse = textandmorse[i].morse;
            }

            if (metode === 1) {
                if (type === "t2m") {
                    from.replace(letter, morse);
                } else if (type === "m2t") {
                    from.replace(morse, letter);
                }
            } else if (metode === 2) {
                if (type === "t2m") {
                    from.replaceArray(letter, morse);
                } else if (type === "m2t") {
                    from.replaceArray(morse, letter);
                }
            }

            if (log === true) {
                console.log(letter + "  ~  " + morse);
            } else {
                console.log("It's Worked ???");
            }
        }

        // Run
        brun.click(function() {
            var res = tam(itext.val(), 1, true, "t2m");
            otext.append(res);
        });

    });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bagusa4/bh1kkjb7/)

Comment: I know this is not the root of the problem, but it looks like you should replace the dot and the hyphen first thing, not when you already filled your string with dots and hyphens.

Comment: What is part of the problem though is that the tam function never returns anything

Comment: I think you should move replace part in `tam` function into `for` loop. And `tam` function should return the value.

Also `from.replace(letter, morse);`

will not change `from` value. You should replace by: `from = from.replace(letter, morse);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a few things to point out:

1. As I said in the comments, `tam()` has no `return` statement, that's why `otext` never gets appended text (even incorrect text).
2. But even if you do return something, the conversion table has no lowercase characters, so most of your text won't get converted. To counter this, you must convert both your text and each of the letters in the conversion table to lowercase
3. As I also pointed in the comments, the fact that the conversion table has the dot and the hyphen mean that when you replace those with their Morse counterparts, all the previously converted code will be messed up (ie. dots and hyphens for every character will be converted to morse for said dots and hyphens). So even if you get dots and hyphens in otext, they will be wrong. To solve this, instead of replacing characters on the same string, you should have a separate string for the result string that `tam()` will return. I will not do this here because your question was why it was not returning anything, and you said you like problems anyway :)

Now to make this work:

1. The first `for` in `tam()` is too short. It should span the whole of `tam()`'s body, otherwise it will just be assigning values to `letter` and `morse`, but after the loop only the last values will survive, and you will only be able to replace the **last** character of your conversion table. So move that loop's closing brace to the last line of your function.
2. In Javascript, `string.replace()` will return a **new string** with the replacement you asked it for, but it will not change the very string object upon which you called `replace`. So both of your calls to `from.replace()` should took like this:

   `from = from.replace(...);`
3. Convert all the alphabetic characters in the conversion table to lowercase, and replace the `letter` in your `from.replace()` statements to `letter.toLowerCase()` so `replace()` will be able to find them.
4. Finally, in the last line of `tam()` (right after the `for` loop, insert this:

   `return from;`

And that's it!

**Edit:**

Using regular expressions poses the risk of unwittingly replacing parts of shorter morse sequences into longer sequences, corrupting them. For example, the word "ART" translates as ".-/.-./-". But when using regex to translate this back, when letter "A" is replaced for sequence ".-", you will end up with "A/A./-", and the R will be corrupted.

To fix this you need to translate sequences one by one for the "m2t" case, like this:

```
  } else if ( type === "m2t" ) {
            var from = tidyMorse(froml).replace(/\s+/g, "");
            var outm = '';

            var morseCodes = from.split('/');
            for (j = 0; j < morseCodes.length; j++) {
                for (i = 0; i < textandmorse.length; i++) {
                    if (morseCodes[j] == textandmorse[i].morse) {
                        outm = outm + textandmorse[i].letter;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return outm;
```

[Check it on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bh1kkjb7/22/)

Comment: I followed your step, but when i convert "A" the result is " .-....-.-.-- " not a " .- " why ? here my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bagusa4/bh1kkjb7/1/ 

before that thanks for your help :)

Comment: I think the likely reason may be what I wrote in point 3 on this answer. Try removing the dot and the hyphen from the conversion table and run again.

Comment: yap, i already do it ... here my edited fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bh1kkjb7/2/ , but when I combine some morse code into the text, the text is still a mess, so what can i do ? :D

Comment: did you try this 'a' translation from scratch? I tried the new fiddle and it works fine for me. But if you try after trying other things then they will accumulate because you use `otext.prepend()`. In that case you should use `otext.text()`

Comment: not, emm..,, I mean, when I want to translate Morse code ".- / .-. / -" to the text, the result became "A ET. / -" which is supposed to be like this "AAET" :D why does it happen ?

Comment: Thanks guys ,,, this end of my code http://jsfiddle.net/bagusa4/bh1kkjb7/26/ , my code has been working well ... :D you're a good man :D thanks for your help and participation :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is a semi-working version: http://jsfiddle.net/efvb5wtk/1/. I removed the code that was not being used in the example. Here is a list of important changes I made:

Morse/Text conversion happens in the `for` loop. This:

```
for (i = 0; i < textandmorse.length; i++) {
    var letter = textandmorse[i].letter;
    var morse = textandmorse[i].morse;
}
```

Will do nothing but set `letter` and `morse` to the last entry in `textandmorse`. You need more code in the `for` loop to accomplish anything.

I added a return value to the `tam` function. Without that, the line

```
var res = tam(itext.val(), 1, true, "t2m");
```

Will always assign `undefined` to `res`.

I changed the loop to process the string one letter at a time. As Nannuo Lei mentioned, having a replacement for the `.` and `-` characters will be a problem if you just make straight replacements.

It is much trickier to translate back if there is no division between Morse letters. How will you tell the difference between "ET" and "A"? Both have a Morse translation of '.-'

Comment: Thanks for your help and your participation :D